# c# regex not removing ampersand

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-z0-9/ -_]");
input = rgx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

Which I thought would remove anything that is not a to z, 0 - 9, a space, dash or underscore.

However, when I pass the following in "Outfalls & Accessories", it doesn't remove the ampersand

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: The `-` inside a character class creates a range. `[ -_]` matches [*a single character in the range between   (index 32) and _ (index 95)*](https://regex101.com/r/2cYQJ5/1). So, a lot more chars will be affected. Either escape it or move to the start/end of the character class, or right before or after a valid range.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks - that's solved it